# Override module javascript file in theme or custom module

Tags: theming, javascript

Is it possible to override a single javascript file from a module within a theme or custom module? My specific use would be for `Views/js/ajax_view.js` - I've had to apply multiple patches to get ajax views to work properly with [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and panels, and though I'm including documentation for future developers, it seems more foolproof to override within the theme or a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

[`hook_js_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) allows you to modify any JS before it is written to the page.
The documentation includes a snippet to replace a core file with an alternate from a module:

```
function hook_js_alter(&$javascript) {
  // Swap out jQuery to use an updated version of the library.
  $javascript['misc/jquery.js']['data'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update') . '/jquery.js';
}
```

Comment: When I `dpm($javascript)`, I don't see any Views-related js that I can edit. I tried this in both my theme `template.php` and in the `.module` file for my feature associated with the view.

Comment: Do you know why Views js would not be present when I use `dpm`?